# How to push to a compose-built image to ECR manually?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecr

I have a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: some-nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443

  mongodb:
    container_name: some-mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
```

I want to push to Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR), using the commands:

```sh
docker tag testapper:latest 619625705037.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testapper:latest
```

But I got an message:

> Error response from daemon: No such image: testapper:latest

When I run `docker-compose build` I got this message:

```
nginx uses an image, skipping
mongodb uses an image, skipping
```

What does this mean? How do push my images to ECR?

Comment: what's testapper? is it an image you built?

Comment: this is the repo name in aws I created

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your docker containers are all using existing images (`image` keyword)

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
```

therefore you do not need to build them.

I believe ECS will find these official images by itself, so you do not need to push them to your private repo (ECR). (not 100% sure)

In case you do want to push a custom built image, the general flow is

```
docker build -t your_image_name:tag path
docker tag your_image_name:tag 619625705037.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/your_image_name:tag
# or
docker build -t 619625705037.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/your_image_name:tag path


docker push 619625705037.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/your_image_name:tag
```

You can use `docker-compose build` to build and tag at the same time if your compose file is like

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: 619625705037.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/your_image_name:tag
    build: ./my-nginx-path
```